# Wall Sconce Light

Tags: building, design

I'm trying to plan a few wall sconces for lighting as in this picture:

[image: big bang theory floor with elevator]

One thought I had was to put a transparent 2x2 round halfway into the wall with half of it hanging out and then put 2 quarter circle tiles on top. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: I assume that you're after minifig scale? Or are you going for the micro scale of most Architecture sets (based on the [tag:architecture] tag)?

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I don't think the tag was chosen for this reason rather than because lamps are an architectural feature. Though, even if it was, this is a general design question unrelated to existing products, so the tag can be removed anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau Agreed, and that was my thought to because the architecture tag defines itself as "Questions relating to the Lego Architecture theme". I was just confirming what the intended scale and use was ;)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you want this in minifigure scale, I would mount part [553c Brick, Round 2 x 2 Dome Top - Hollow Stud with Bottom Axle Holder x Shape + Orientation](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=553c&idColor=12&name=Trans-Clear%20Brick,%20Round%202%20x%202%20Dome%20Top%20-%20Hollow%20Stud%20with%20Bottom%20Axle%20Holder%20x%20Shape%20%20%20Orientation&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=S&C=12&O=%7B%22color%22:12,%22loc%22:%22US%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) upside down in the wall, topped with a [18674 Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Open Stud in Black](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15535&name=Tile,%20Round%202%20x%202%20with%20Hole&category=%5BTile,%20Round%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:%2211%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) mounted right-side up. You will need to do some clever SNOTting to make that all fit, but an upside-down [3659 Brick, Arch 1 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3659&name=Brick,%20Arch%201%20x%204&category=%5BBrick,%20Arch%5D#T=S&C=2&O=%7B%22color%22:%222%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) could hold the dome brick and the round tile can be held in place with a regular brick.

[image]

[image]

Here is how this would look like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: technically this doesn’t fit (the dome sticks out of the top of the inverted arch brick by just a smidge too much) but due to tolerances you can make this work. I used a white dome brick because I didn’t have a trans-clear one handy.